# Search for exact string in column

Tags: text-processing, grep

I have a file with words separated by ',' on lines, every line has the same number of words, say 4. So ther are in the form  of:

`something1,something2,something3,something4`

I want to search for the line that contains on the 4th column exactly `something4`, but how do i do that if there exists another line that is something like this:

`something1,something2,something3,1_something4`

with grep I will get both these lines, but I only want the line that has on the 4th element exactly `something4` what should I do?

Comment: You might be interested in my answer here: [How can I extract/change lines in a text file whose data are separated into fields?](//unix.stackexchange.com/a/210337)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use `awk` for this:

```
awk -F, '$4 == "something4"' file.csv
```

This should print the entire line for any line where the 4th column is exactly `something4`

---

In order to pass a variable into `awk` you would need to do the following:

```
var1=$(echo "something,something4" | cut -f2 -d,)
awk -F, -vsearch="$var1" '$4 == search' file.csv
```

Comment: Why doesn't this work if I do if with a variable?

Comment: Say I have ```var1=$(echo "something,something4" | cut -f2 -d,)``` and I try to
```awk -F, '$4 == "$var1"' file.csv``` but if I go and ``` echo "$var1"``` I get the good result, and there exits ```something4``` in file.csv

Comment: @C.Cristi: I have updated my answer.  Let me know if it doesn't work for you.

Comment: It works, but why?

Comment: Your shell variable won't expand inside the single quotes around the awk command.  So awk has the -v option to pass variables into the awk program.

Comment: awk does backslash interpretation on `-v` variables so if you want to be paranoid you may want to use an environment variables instead. Contrast the output of `awk -v x='ab\\d' '{print x}' <<<''` with that of `x='ab\\d' awk '{print ENVIRON["x"]}' <<<''`

Answer (score 10):

Or, since there's only 4 columns and you want something specific in the last one,

```
grep ',something4$' < input
```

(posted in case you're actually OK with grep; [awk](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/483285/117549) is a great solution here).

Answer (score 0):

Generally, for this type of problem you can use `cut` to get only the column you want, then `grep` on that.

`echo something1,something2,something3,something4 | cut -d , -f 4 | grep '^something4$'`

Comment: The only problem with this is the assumption that the OP wants to find the _line_ that matches.

Comment: You're right. `cut` would only be useful for checking for match/no match or counting matches. Or finding all column values that match a regexp.